# How to import python class file from same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a directory in my Python 3.3 project called /models.

from my `main.py` I simply do a

```
from models import *
```

in my `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ["Engine","EngineModule","Finding","Mapping","Rule","RuleSet"]
from models.engine import Engine,EngineModule
from models.finding import Finding
from models.mapping import Mapping
from models.rule import Rule
from models.ruleset import RuleSet
```

This works great from my application.

I have a model that depends on another model, such that in my `engine.py` I need to import `finding.py` in `engine.py`. When I do: `from finding import Finding`

I get the error `No Such Module exists`.

How can I import class B from file A in the same module/directory?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.3

Comment: Python 3 doesn't allow implicit relative imports.

Comment: @Yablargo Can you move your _Edit 1_ section and post as self-answer (`from .finding import Finding`)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3, which disallows these relative imports (it can lead to confusion between modules of the same name in different packages).

Use either:

```
from models import finding
```

or

```
import models.finding
```

or, probably best:

```
from . import finding  # The . means "from the same directory as this module"
```

Comment: I think that last one should be `from . import finding` (otherwise, SyntaxError is raised -- at least for me on python 3.5).

Comment: I suppose from . import finding is better because it doesn't hardcode the directory name, also any possible name class with another module is averted this way

Comment: `from .models import finding` also should work (at least for Python 3.5)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I can do: `from .finding import Finding` and this works.

And the answer below reflects this as well so I guess this is reasonably correct.

I've fixed up my file naming and moved my tests to a different directory and I am running smoothly now. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in Python 3.7