# Python cannot import one of two identical classes int the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

When running a python script, I'm trying to import two different classes from two different scripts from the same directory.
The first one works, the second one fails, for reasons I have not been able to figure out.

I took all of the useful code out of the imported scripts and made them identical except for the class names to try to limit the number of variables while I was testing solutions.

I had been following along these two guides when the issues occurred

- [Writing your own programming language and compiler with Python](https://blog.usejournal.com/writing-your-own-programming-language-and-compiler-with-python-a468970ae6df)
- [rply Generating Parsers](https://rply.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide/parsers.html)

I'm sure it's a mind-numbingly simple fix, but I have not yet been able to figure it out.

Thanks for your help.

---

**Python Version**

`Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

**Folder Structure**

- `MSAs`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `lexer.py`
  - `main.py`
  - `parser.py`

**File Contents**

`__init__.py`

```
"""empty file"""
```

lexer.py

```
class Lexer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 'world'
```

parser.py

```
class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 'world'
```

main.py

```
from lexer import Lexer
from parser import Parser

p = Parser()
```

**Running the script from the `MSAs` folder**

`msas> python main.py`

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'`

---

**Things the internet told me to try, and their results**

I feel like a few of these are common sense that they did not work but I was attempting to exhaust all my options.

[prefix the module name with a `.` if not using a subdirectory:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142178/1442991)

`No module named '__main__.lexer'; '__main__' is not a package`

[change to `import parser.Parser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21139466/1442991)

`No module named 'parser.Parser'; 'parser' is not a package`

[change to `from . import Parser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21139466/1442991)

`AttributeError: module 'parser' has no attribute 'Parser'`

[insert the working directly into sys.path](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/python-import/)

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'`

Switch the order of the import statements

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'`

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parser` is a module in Python's [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html), so I believe your code is trying to import `Parser` from that file, not from your `parser.py` file. Since that object does not exist, you get the `ImportError` you see.

Comment: changed my ```parser.py``` to ```queryParser.py``` and the import in ```main.py``` to ```from queryParser import Parser``` and it worked perfectly. thank you

Comment: I don't understand why this fixed the issue.  If `parser.py` was in the current directory, that should have been found by the import first, before the standard library module, right?