# How to import classes and function from files within the same dir as main.py in Python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am struggling with importing local source files that reside in the same directory as  `main.py` in Python 3.9. I had it working before but
couldn't tell why it was working. After a while it stopped working.

I created a minimal example to reproduce the problem with the structure shown below.

I have read some [available answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139364/how-to-import-python-class-file-from-same-directory) that suggest using `from . import car` in `main.py` which resulted in the
following Error:

```
(venv) [.../pyimport_example/productname]  python3 ./main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myUser/pyimport_example/productname/./main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import car
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Got the same error when using `from .car import Car`

I have also tried to run `main.py` as a module as suggested in "[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3):

```
(venv) [.../pyimport_example/productname] python3 -m main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/Users/myUser/pyimport_example/productname/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .car import Car
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

The answer to "[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) seems to focus on the case where one want to run a python file as a
script inside a package, which is not the problem I am having.

### My sample project

```
pyimport_example
├── README.md
├── productname
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── car.py
│   └── main.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

content of `main.py`

```py
from .car import Car


def main():
    print("Maria ist cool.")

    mycar = Car("Ford", "Mustang", "1966")
    mycar.print_car()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

contents of `car.py`

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year_manufacture):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year_manufacture = year_manufacture

    def print_model(self):
        print("{0} {1} {2}".format(self.year_manufacture, self.make, self.model))
```

Is there a fix without modifying the system path?

Comment: Are you using Spyder IDE by any chance?

Comment: No, but I need to say no in minimum 15 characters.

Comment: Your project package is outside of the virtual environment.

Comment: Think in terms of packages and scripts, not directories and files. Your `productname` directory is used to define a package named `productname`,  but `main.py` is a script that is separate from `productname` (though it *imports* it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your `__init__.py`-File.

In the folder `productname` you wanna specify what imports you can run from a module on the same level:

```
from .car import *
```

Now you should be able to import your file into your `main.py` with:

```
from car import Car
```

Comment: It works! would you be so kind and give a little bit more info on why that works?

Comment: Glad to hear!

I would take a look into https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.
This explains everything needed in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

for me the answer seem to have been to simply:

```
import car
```